# Performance test kafka consumer/producer

Tags: performance, stress-testing

I've developed a consumer kafka that does the following: 
    - get an event on a kafka topic.
    - carries out some operations
    - emits one or more events on kafka topics

I would like to find a solution to measure the performance of this component (execution time between the reception of messages and the transmission of other messages).

I have looking for a solution using Jmeter or Gateling. But I have not found any solution.

Do you have any idea, or any link to help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the component you've developed is consuming, processing and emitting messages than it is both Kafka *consumer* and *producer*.

If you want to test your component in isolation, i.e., measure the time it takes for your component to process a message, you can mock Kafka, mock Kafka consuming and producing parts or write your code in such a way the processing part is Kafka-agnostic and can be tested in isolation. You can read more here:

- [Kafka: Are there are examples on how to use Mockito for unit testing Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417720/kafka-are-there-are-examples-on-how-to-use-mockito-for-unit-testing-kafka)
- [Python: how to mock a kafka topic for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340100/python-how-to-mock-a-kafka-topic-for-unit-tests)

Once you have your component isolated, you may measure processing time with any performance framework.

If you, however, want to measure performance of Kafka configuration then I suggest reading: 
[Benchmarking Apache Kafka: 2 Million Writes Per Second (On Three Cheap Machines)](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines).

There are also [Gatling plugins](https://github.com/mnogu/gatling-kafka) for Kafka producer protocol.